# Is Connecting to MySQL Through a Program Safe?

Tags: c++, mysql, security

So recently I figured out you can connect to an SQL database through a c++ program. I'd like to use this, however, I'm wondering how safe this is. More specifically, would someone be able to take this program and reverse it somehow to reveal any info or more importantly the database login info.

Comment: You shouldn't store the login details *in* the program.

Comment: It depends. MySQL allows several connection types. Some are cleat text others are fully encrypted with SSL. How are you connecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, someone would be able to. You should assume that if someone has access to the binary, he could easily get it. Even if you obfuscate the credentials it would do very little to actually stop someone from reversing the code to see how you read it in your code (security by obscurity isn’t security).

Don’t ever keep credentials on the client side.